# Most intuitive accordion action icon

Tags: interaction-design, user-expectation, icons, accordion, behavior-design

There's a lot of buzz and fuzz about the icon usage for an accordion header (state changing button).

After a short research, I came to the conclusion to use **up and down arrows** and I was wondering if anyone can provide a better reasoning about icons usage for this matter.

My logic when choosing this option (up and down arrows) was the following:

- When I see a **down arrow**, I expect something to happen in this direction (from top to bottom). The same logic applies for the **up icon**;
- I rejected the idea of using +/- symbols since the action of expanding/collapsing doesn't relate to addition/subtraction symbols.
- I also wanted to keep things consistent, as we had some drop-down menus which use the same arrow approach.

*There was one more variation: using the **greater than** symbol for initial state (collapsed) and the **up arrow** for expanded state. I also find this approach a little bit confusing, since the **left arrow** and **right arrow** symbols make more sense when having a left-to-right navigation or a step-by-step action.*

Does any of you know a better/intuitive aproach for this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other questions with this same theme, you can take a look at: [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83197/which-accordion-identifiers-work-best) and [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37686/how-should-you-show-that-an-accordion-is-expanded)

These posts can help you :)

In my opinion, I prefer the icons of more and less

> The plus icon is the clearer affordance for menu expansion. Another
>   research study on accordions found that users click the plus icon more
>   than the arrow one. This makes sense because the plus sign is the
>   mathematical symbol for addition. When you add, you increase in
>   amount, number or degree. Users increase the number of menu options
>   when they click the accordion menu.

More about it [here](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/where-to-place-your-accordion-menu-icons/)

Comment: Thanks for the quote and the link, I already checked it, but I didn't found any valid "research study" that they point to. I also had a look in Material Design guidelines and found it more clearly explained and reasoned, but I'm still a bit into doubt. The material guideline is anyway a valuable resouce: https://material.io/guidelines/components/expansion-panels.html#expansion-panels-behavior

Comment: The best way to find out which icon is best for your interface is to do the user test, so you will not have any doubts :)

Comment: True, A/B testing is a good option, but not in the initial state. That's why I'm trying to choose the best fit at the moment (based on people who already tried and failed/succeeded), suitable for a positive starting point.

Comment: @n1kkou A/B testing != user testing. I think what Maisa was getting at was, there is not a universally "right" or "optimum" way to solve design problems like the one you pose—the surest way to assess the efficacy of a design is to conduct a usability study of your app/prototype, and see if _your_ users struggle with it or not. If they don't, you can move on to other problems.

Comment: You are right @NateGreen

Answer (score 0):

Nielsen Norman Group did a study on it and recommend down carets to show it can be expanded, transforming to an up carets (^) to show it can be collapsed again:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/accordion-icons/